# Use substitution string in PL/SQL anonymous block

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex, substitution

Is there any way to use a substitution string in PL/SQL anonymous block ? I tried to use my substitution string `DATE_DIFF` inside a PL/SQL anonymous block as `&DATE_DIFF.` But it gives below error.

> `ORA-06550: line 13, column 18: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "&"
>   when expecting one of the following: ( - + all case mod new null <an
>   identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
>   continue any avg count current max min prior some sql stddev sum
>   variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval date <a string
>   literal with character set specification> <a number> <a single-quoted
>   SQL string> pipe <an alternatively-quoted string literal with
>   character set s`

How can i solve this ?

**UPDATED**

sample code of using substitution string in PL/SQL anonymous block.

```
DECLARE
 v_date_diff NUMBER;
BEGIN

 v_date_diff := &DATE_DIFF.; // this didn't work

END;
```

Comment: Substitution variables are SQLP*PLUS related feature. Some other tools may or may not support them.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Oracle APEX support for substitution string.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken in APEX in PL/SQL block, syntax for substitution variable would be  `:DATE_DIFF` or using `V` function `V('DATE_DIFF')`.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Yes. `:DATE_DIFF` did the work. Thanks :). post this as a answer and i'll accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In APEX, you use substitution string syntax (`&DATE_DIFF.`) when you want to retrieve session state for an item into tabs, lists, and so forth. In order to retrieve session state for an item in PL/SQL block, you either prefix item name with colon, or use `V()` function:

1. `:DATE_DIFF`
2. `v('DATE_DIF')`